# Is this use of Javascript eval() 100% safe?

Tags: javascript, security, eval

I'm writing a PHP library which generates Javascript code.

The Javascript code has a number of components named `component001`, `component002`, etc.

Pages are loaded dynamically via AJAX.

I need to pass the name of the component via URL variable which is then evaled() by the script.

The only way I am protecting what is being evaled is with the regular expression `^component[0-9]{3}$`: if it passes it gets evaled, otherwise it does not.

**To me this is 100% safe since nothing will get executed unless it is simply the name of one of my known components, or is there something about the `eval()` command that could be exploited in this code sample, e.g. regex injection, some kind of cross site scripting etc.?**

```
window.onload = function() {

    // *** DEFINED IN ANOTHER JAVASCRIPT FILE:
    var component001 = 'testing111';
    var component002 = 'testing222';
    var component003 = 'testing333';

    var APP = {};

    APP.getUrlVars = function() {
        var vars = [], hash;
        var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
        for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
            hash = hashes[i].split('=');
            vars.push(hash[0]);
            vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
        }
        return vars;
    }

    APP.getUrlVar = function(name, defaultValue) {
        defaultValue = (typeof defaultValue == 'undefined') ? '' : defaultValue;
        var vars = APP.getUrlVars();
        if(vars[name] === undefined)
        {
            return defaultValue;
        } else {
            return vars[name];
        }
    }

    APP.safeEval = function(nameOfComponent) {
        var REGEX_VALID_NAME = /^component[0-9]{3}$/;
        if(REGEX_VALID_NAME.test(nameOfComponent)) {
            return eval(nameOfComponent);
        } else {
            return 'ERROR';
        }

    }

    // *** JAVASCRIPT FILE LOADED VIA AJAX:

    var nameOfComponentToDisplay = APP.getUrlVar('compname', 'component001');
    var component = APP.safeEval(nameOfComponentToDisplay);
    document.write(component);

}
```

Comment: Instead of using `eval` for this, I'd use the square bracket notation to call your function (e.g. `APP[nameOfComponent]();`)

Comment: regex and eval() are both open ended tools that introduce risk. The problem you describe need not embrace that risk. Instead - as @Marcel Korpel and @ChaosPandio have writ - use string matching and function invoking to avoid.

Comment: The only excuse I can think of to use `eval()` is if you're writing something like the Firebug console. As other answers show, most places where you might consider using `eval` can be acheived better without it anyway. And in ihe few remaining scenarios where `eval()` may genuinely be useful, it should certainly not be considered safe.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is almost zero reasons to use `eval` and I think that this is not one of them. Remember that all objects act like dictionaries so you can simply do something like this:

```
var components = {
    component001 : 'testing111',
    component002 : 'testing222',
    component003 : 'testing333'
};

APP.safeEval = function(nameOfComponent) {
    var result = components[nameOfComponent];
    if(result) {
        return result;
    } else {
        return 'ERROR';
    }
}
```

Comment: ... and you should probably be using an array anyway if you've got a list of objects.

Answer (score 4):

Well, if all there is is a name, then

```
  eval(component101)
```

won't do anything anyway, so it seems safe.  Maybe you meant

```
  return eval(nameOfComponent + '()');
```

If so, then I don't see why you don't just put your components in a namespace object. Then you wouldn't need eval at all:

```
  return components[nameOfComponent]();
```

If they're not functions, then the same thing applies, but you'd leave off the "()".

Answer (score 3):

If the variables are defined in another javascript file and contain only numbers and letters, then they are part of the global namespace. As such, they can be accessed as properties of the `window` object (no need for `eval`!):

```
if (typeof window[nameOfComponent] !== 'undefined')
    return window[nameOfComponent]
return 'ERROR';
```

Comment: If you are using anything less than ECMAScript 5 you want to use `typeof x === "undefined"` because `undefined` is a mutable variable.

Comment: If you want to know whether there is a property with that name, then `nameOfComponent in window` will do that and not fail around defined properties whose value is `undefined`.